# How can Time and Date be automatically updated when a data is inserted or updated in oracle?

Tags: oracle

I want that every time a data is input in oracle table the date and time must automatically be updated in one of the column named 'CREATION_DATE'.

Comment: This can be accomplished by using either a default value of SYSDATE, or a trigger which ensures it is filled. The correct answer would depend on your exact needs and code. For example, a default value can be overridden if NULL is explicitly provided in the INSERT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting default value of SYSDATE is more efficient than a trigger. As helpc mentioned, a default value can be overridden if NULL is explicitly provided in the INSERT. If you don't intend to pass date time thru application at all, you can define the column as NOT NULL with a default as sysdate .

Comment: And how does the default value help for UPDATEs?

Comment: Yes, I have used the SYSDATE functionality. Its more efficient and less head scratching.
Thanks

Comment: However I would also want to know if time can also be accomodated?

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name for your comment!

snigdha - 'date' type column contains time as well. 
Change ‘nls_date_format’ in your sql_plus session and you can see it.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

As a_horse_with_no_name  rightly pointed out, you cannot update the timestamp automatically for subsequent changes on that row. You will need to have one more audit column ‘modified_date’ which you could/should SYSDATE during UPDATEs. Triggers should be avoided, though.

Answer (score 0):

A trigger will do what you want. I think something like this is what you are looking for:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER date_trigger
  AFTER INSERT ON your_table
  FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.your_table> 0)
BEGIN
    :NEW.CREATION_DATE:= SYSDATE;
END;
/
```

Depending on your needs I usually like to add both a create_date and an update_date column to pick up timestamps for changes that may occur later.

Comment: How do you record the timestamp of a `delete` thought? (Without that, the whole concept is logically inconsistent with itself.) My point being, why do you need to keep track of this information?